# cannot open display "default display" in Linux Mint 15

Tags: linux-mint, x11, xfce

I have a really strange problem, i rebooted my laptop running Linux Mint 15 with XFCE and unexpectedly it doesn't show the login screen instead i see `tty1`. The strange part is, that i haven't changed any configurations before the reboot. The system was running flawlessly weeks before today.

At boot i see the animated splash logo, and then i am presented with the blinking cursor of the `tty1`. To check if my graphic card works I've rebooted to windows (it's a dual boot system). Windows works without problems.

I also tried to boot older kernel versions, i checked the filesystems, everything ok. When i call `startx` from one of the ttys, i see my desktop without any XFCE stuff, no panels nothing. Cant open a terminal etc.

Currently i am writing the last parts of my bachelor thesis, this problem is the total worst case. I am not to familiar with X11 and friends, that means i don't know where to look for the problem.

PS: The laptop is a hp elitebook 8460p, with integrated intel hd graphics. I am running the included open source graphic drivers.

**UPDATE**:
When i call `startxfce4` in a `tty` after i logged in on that terminal, i get my desktop back. But why is there no login screen after all? Someone any ideas?
`mdm` is responsible for the login screen in linux mint, i think that there is the problem.

**UPDATE-2**:
When i call `mdm` in the `tty` after booting, the login screen shows up and i can login. But  why doesn't start mdm automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the `fontconfig-infinality` package.

Solution:

1. `sudo apt-get purge fontconfig-infinality`
2. `sudo apt-get remove mdm && sudo apt-get install mdm` (maybe not necessary)
3. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mdm`

Voila! The login screen is back. The only downside is, i did'nt get an answer why this error has come up so randomly.